# AngularJS Controller is not a function error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting error when adding `ng-controller="HeaderController"` to a div.

```
Error: ng:areq
Bad Argument
Argument 'HeaderController' is not a function, got undefined
```

my HTML looks like that:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="HeaderController">
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="PostController">
    </div>
</div>
```

Also I include following files:

MyApp.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['postServices', 'angularFileUpload', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.date', 'bootstrapLightbox', 'profileServices']);
```

HeaderController.js

```
myApp.controller('HeaderController', ['$scope', 'PostServices', '$http', function($scope, PostServices, $http) {
    $scope.getBookmarksCount = function() {
        PostServices.getBookmarksCount().then(function(response) {
            if (response.data.status == 'success') {
                $scope.bookmarksCount = response.data.bookmarksCount;
            } else {
                $scope.errorMessage = response.data.message;
            }
        })
    };
}]);
```

PostController.js beggining of this file looks like:

```
   myApp.controller('PostController', ['$scope', 'PostServices', '$http', 'FileUploader', 'Lightbox',function($scope, PostServices, $http, FileUploader, Lightbox) {
```

PostService.js contains a module named `postServices` and it contains a service `PostServices`:

```
angular.module('postServices', [])
    .service('PostServices', ['$http', function($http) {
```

if I delete `ng-controller="HeaderController"` everything works fine.

Does anyone knows what could be the problem?

Comment: is `HeaderController.js` included in your html ?

Comment: the question says that the file is included

Comment: You should check dependencies in both controller. I think you should remove that dependencies one by one & check which dependency is causing the problem, in this way you get proper solution or either you can upload full code here to review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which version of Angular you use , I took 1.4.0 for my plunk example and try just to limit to the code you provide to see if I recreated the error.

I had to deal more with scripts inclusion order. It created error. The right order in order to make it work is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
<script src="MyApp.js"></script>  
<script src="PostController.js"></script>
<script src="PostService.js"></script>
<script src="HeaderController.js"></script>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/NhzQFmI1s9r98uAMZwYg

So Main point was to defined PostService.js before HeaderController

Answer (score 1):

In your module you add the postServices without a capital at the start, while you add it in your headercontroller as PostServices. This might mess with the forming of your headercontroller.

Either one of those could be a typo, but it is very important that you inject the service precisely as it is defined (in your .service or .factory) in the `['PostService',` bit. So if the service is called: postService, you should inject it in your controller as: `['postService, function(someNameThatDoesntMatter)`  if its called PostService, inject it as `['PostService', function(someNameThatDoesntMatter)`

As I just shown, how you call it afterwards in the function parameter is up to you.

**Update**

You could create a module for your controllers to fix this. Make sure to inject your postServices in this module aswell. Then inject the controllers module in your myApp module :-) The benefit of working in a structured way like this, is that you can create a structure of including your JS which you can apply on every project you work on.

Comment: Update my question with PostController.js header. PostServices shouldn't be a problem. But despite that I tried that to make sure and I still get the error

Comment: there is a module called `postServices` and it has a service called `PostServices`

Comment: So the PostController is working with the service injected, but the header controller isn't?

Comment: yes exactly. I don't even change the files included just adding `ng-controller="HeaderController"` to the `div` tag

Comment: What happens if you change the order of including? e.g, header controller in front of postcontroller?

Comment: In any case, if you are as far as making a separate module for your services, why not make a module for your controllers aswell? This would prevent errors like these to happen in the future :-)

Comment: how about you create 1 file called 'controllers.js' and put those 2 controllers behind eachother

Answer (score 0):

It seems likes

you forget include that `HeaderController.js` file in index.html.

Make sure your `HeaderController.js` is loaded properly.

Missing some where in gulp/grunt process.

Comment: I didn't. I've double checked it. and also checked the source of the page. the file is included just fine

Comment: The question says that the file is included. If you want to clarify that, please do it in a comment and not in an answer.

Comment: Is it included after the module is created?

Comment: yes. includes goes as follow: MyApp.js PostController.js HeaderController.js and other services files.